# Backing up ASP.net website code files - to a backup folder under the website folder

Tags: asp.net, iis

I want to backup my existing ASP.net web app before updating it.

Therefore I create a backup folder inside the website (ie same level as App_Code, web.config). Call it something like Backup_20110910

Then I move all the current website files/folders (excluding web.config, app_data) into the backup folder.

Then I extract the zip of the latest code in the now clean folder.

Is there any potential problems with this approach? As after all, you are increasing the number of csharp files in your website folder, could there be conflicts etc.

Comment: I would keep the backup outside the web root.  I would probably leave it zipped up as well, but that's just me.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Looks like I should backup outside the web root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There won't be an issue - except that it might become confusing to have identical folder structures within the current folder structure - it's always wisest to keep backups completly seperate from the current build

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't back up within the folder structure, there's a possibility that someone then finds your backup folders and browses to them, running the older code. If you zip it then you suddenly have files someone can download too. Even more amusingly if, as a lot of people do, when you change web.config you rename the old one to web.config.bak a lot of security scanners look for that because now it can be downloaded, as it's no longer a .config file, but a .bak.

Backup outside the web root, not within and all of those worries will go away.